# Snowflake dbt connectin Fail on github

Tags: docker, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, github-actions, dbt

Using this cicd yml file in github.

```
name: dbt Build and Push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    container:
      image: xemuliam/dbt:1.5

    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

        run: |
          dbt debug
          dbt seed
          dbt docs generate
```

Few days back cicd was working fine. Got this in console.

```
04:26:28  Connection:
04:26:28    account: myaccount
04:26:28    user: ***
04:26:28    database: mydb
04:26:28    schema: dev
04:26:28    warehouse: DBT
04:26:28    role: SYSADMIN
04:26:28    client_session_keep_alive: False
04:26:28    query_tag: None
04:26:28  Registered adapter: snowflake=1.5.2
04:26:29    Connection test: [OK connection ok]
```

But now it gives me this

```
Connection test: [ERROR]
09:06:46  dbt was unable to connect to the specified database.
The database returned the following error:

  >Database Error
  Error detecting the version of libcrypto
```

Also when I tried "dbt debug" locally it is working fine. It also works fine on gitlab cicd.

I have changed nothing in code or any config but connection is failing.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/wbond/oscrypto/issues/78#issuecomment-1741032472

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to come from the python package oscrypto:
https://github.com/wbond/oscrypto/issues/78

Replacing the oscrypto requirement by pointing on the particular commit `d5f3437` corrects the issue. Once a new release is pushed 1.3.1 you need to use this one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with:
`poetry add oscrypto@git+https://github.com/wbond/oscrypto.git@d5f3437ed24257895ae1edd9e503cfb352e635a8`